# How to use jQuery Uniform with Rails 3

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails-3, uniform

I'm trying to get the Default Uniform up on my rails webapp, but have not yet found any solid tutorial/guide.  I've confirmed that I have the jquery gem

In my Gemfile:

```
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'
```

and then ran in the terminal from within my app directory to make sure:

```
bundle install
```

I put uniform.default.css in my stylesheets directory, jquery.uniform.js in my javascripts directory, and the images in my images directory.  I then include them in my view with the form:

```
  1 <!-- for jQuery uniform -->
  2 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8/jquery.min.js"></script>
  3 <%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.uniform.js" %>
  4 <%= stylesheet_link_tag "uniform.default.css" %>
  5 <script type='text/javascript'>
  6   // On load, style typical form elements
  7   $(function () {
  8     $("select, input, button, textarea, submit").uniform();
  9   });
 10 </script>
 11 <!-- end for jQuery uniform -->
```

No, images are showing up though!  I peeked into the source of uniform.default.css file and found that all the images are relative to the current directory:

```
  background-image: url("../images/sprite.png");
```

Luckily, that still seems to be the case the way the default tree of the rails 3 app is set up, but there are issues.  I also tried editing every instance of this to be an absolute path that I've confirmed to be valid with another image.  e.g.:

```
  background-image: url("/assets/images/sprite.png");
```

But still no luck.  Any ideas?  Does the javascript also depend on a particular path for the images?  It shouldn't, right?

Comment: I should also add that I've removed my css specific to the test page and am still getting the issue.  I've also tried uniform.default and uniform.agent.  Images seem to be missing regardless of the style I choose.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the files in the vendor/assets directory.
in there put the css in the

```
vendor/assets/stylesheets
```

the js in

```
vendor/assets/javascripts
```

and the images in

```
vendor/assets/images
```

and than in add the following line to app/assets/stylesheets/application.css:

```
*= require uniform.agent
```

Rename the js file that you placed in vendor/assets/javascripts to uniform.js
and add this in the app/assets/javascripts/application.js

```
//= require uniform
```

Comment: I've removed the javascript_include_tag and stylesheet_link_tag as they are now in the overarching  css and js files...but still no luck.  Continuing to iterate.  I still have the javascript in the view.

Comment: I also am no longer manually editing the path to the images.  It is as it was originally: the ../images one

Comment: once you put things in de vendor directory you should be able to use them as if they were in the normal images directory, so, from css you do url("assets/my_img.png").

Answer (score 0):

Phew!  Took some experimentation, but finally integrated jQuery Uniform like so:

Ensure you have the jQuery gem installed by including this in your Gemfile:`gem 'jquery-rails', '2.0.2'`

Download whatever style you're interested in from: http://uniformjs.com/#themes

Add the images to /vendor/assets/images, the javascript file to vendor/assets/javascripts and the stylesheet to vendor/assets/stylesheets.

Edit any background url image paths in the css file from: url('../images/imagename.png') to

```
url('/assets/imagename.png')
```

So all these assets are eventually plopped into one big directory I guess, named assets.  The separation is only for the developer's sanity.

I also made sure to include that in the head of my main layout, `application.html.erb`:

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "application", :media => "all" %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag "uniform.aristo", :media => "all" %>  <!-- for jQuery Uniform -->
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
<%= javascript_include_tag "jquery.uniform" %> <!-- for jQuery Uniform -->
```

That's all.  No obscure editing of config files or random bug fixes that need other fixes that require more wizard code, ...

It's much more straightforward now that I got a version working and then stripped away any potential influence from all my other experiments.

Hope it helps.